# Compare two dictionaries and add the identified key and difference in value to a new dict

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary

I have two dictionary and I am trying to use a For loop mix with If conditional to achieve the following.

1. For each "item" in the meal_recipe, check if item is in pantry.
2. If yes, check if "value" of meal_recipe is more than pantry. If yes add key + difference in value in shopping_list.
3. If no, add both Key & value of meal_recipe to shopping_list.

```
meal_recipe = {'pasta': 2, 'garlic': 2, 'sauce': 3,
          'basil': 4, 'salt': 1, 'pepper': 2,
          'olive oil': 2, 'onions': 2, 'mushrooms': 6}

pantry = {'pasta': 3, 'garlic': 4,'sauce': 2,
          'basil': 2, 'salt': 3, 'olive oil': 3,
          'rice': 3, 'bread': 3, 'peanut butter': 1,
          'flour': 1, 'eggs': 1, 'onions': 1, 'mushrooms': 3,
          'broccoli': 2, 'butter': 2,'pickles': 6, 'milk': 2,
          'chia seeds': 5}
```

I am a noob in python so I got stuck to at the code below so far and not sure how to proceed:

```
for item, stock in meal_recipe.items():
    if item in pantry:
         if mean_recipe [stock] > pantry [stock]: ????? Not sure
                Shopping_list={item for item in mean_recipe} ????? Not sure
```

Can someone show me how it should be done?

Comment: First step: get the indentation correct. Python requires this.

Comment: What are `meal_recipe` and `pantry`? Shouldn't those be `Dict1` and `Dict2`?

Comment: The instruction says "for each item in dict2". Why are you looping over `Dict1.items()`? Shouldn't that be `Dict2.items()`?

Comment: It would actually be easier to understand if you used the variables `meal_recipe`, `pantry`, and `shopping_list` instead of meaningless names like `Dict1` and `Dict2`.

Comment: "If no, add both Key & value of meal_recipe to shopping_list." Well, if you want to *add something to* the `shopping_list`, it should *exist* first, right? And then, think about what's involved in adding to it.

Comment: "if mean_recipe [stock] > pantry [stock]: ????? Not sure" Think carefully about what the value of `item` will be each time through the loop, and what the value of `stock` will be each time through the loop. Which makes sense to use as a key for `pantry`? Also: when you wrote `for item, stock in meal_recipe.items():`, think carefully about why you chose to iterate over the `.items()`, and not over `.keys()` or `.values()`. (It's correct, but you need to understand what you're doing in order to keep going.)

Answer (score 1):

`stock` is not a dictionary key, it's the value from `meal_recipe`. The key is `item`. So you should use `pantry[item]`, not `pantry[stock]`.

Instead of checking explicitly whether the item is in the dictionary, you can use the `dict.get()` method, which allows you to specify a default value. That way, you can treat an item that isn't in the dictionary as having quantity 0, which will always be less than the quantity you need.

```
for ingredient, qty_needed in meal_recipe.items():
    qty_in_pantry = pantry.get(ingredient, 0)
    if qty_needed > qty_in_pantry:
        shopping_list[ingredient] = qty_needed - qty_in_pantry
```

If the shopping list could already have items and you might want to increase the quantity to buy, you can also use `.get()` there:

```
shopping_list[ingredient] = shopping_list.get(ingredient, 0) + qty_needed - qty_in_pantry
```

Comment: I would even go a step further and rename the dict key variable "item" --> "ingredient". It confuses things when you are using the .items() method.

Comment: @LastTigerEyes Good idea, I changed it while updating the answer to stop mentioning Dict1 and Dict2.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the insight. I will try this out.

Comment: @Barmar, I think your code has a slight bug in it. `qty_in_pantry = pantry.get(ingredient, 0):` doesn't need a colon at the end, since it's an assignment, and that means the next two lines can be un-indented.

Comment: @LastTigerEyes Thanks. That was left over from an earlier version that had another if